# Trying to compile a smart contract Error: Type literal_string

Tags: addresses, error

I'm learning smart contract, and I have a problem compiling one it gives me this error message:

> Error: Type literal_string "0x5c15741c7abb1b0e8fb0bd41b5ed8c17219926a1" is not implicitly convertible to expected type address.
>       address multisig = "0x5c15741c7abb1b0e8fb0bd41b5ed8c17219926a1";

I have tried to me it looks like that, we shouldn't hard code the contract address?

here is the code of the line causing trouble :

> ```
> address multisig = "0x5c15741c7abb1b0e8fb0bd41b5ed8c17219926a1";
> ```

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

## Explicit declaration as an address

You'll want to explicitly define the address instead of trying to force cast a string as an address.

To do this simply use the `address()` operator to make an address type value from the hexadecimal representation of the address.

### Example:

```
address multisig = address(0x5c15741c7abb1b0e8fb0bd41b5ed8c17219926a1);
```

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as the correct answer. If not let me know so I can further assist.

Comment: this still gives an error, "This looks like an address but has an invalid checksum"

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to initialize an address is to not use quotes

```
address a = 0x5c15741c7abb1b0e8fb0bd41b5ed8c17219926a1;
```

But this generates a warning, solidity want addresses with the [mixed case checksum](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-55.md)

```
address b = 0x5c15741C7ABb1b0E8FB0BD41b5ed8c17219926A1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are not using mixed case checksum.

Go to this link below and use toChecksumAddress function with your lowercased address here. And use the result.

https://web3-tools.netlify.app/

Example)
[image]